# Why several bytes of garbage PuTTY (Win7) to Android via WiFi?

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp, telnet

I'm a beginner in socket/tcp/whatever programming and I'm facing a little problem. I develop an Android application that receives data from a PC via WiFi (*hosted network* actually). To test it I use PuTTY in telnet and most of the things are going well.

The problem is that I always receive several bytes of garbage in the first readout of the input stream of the socket.

**Android code (abbrev.)** (I don't add the `try/catch` to make it short)

```
ServerSocket SS = new ServerSocket(port);
Socket S = SS.accept();

S.setSoTimeout(1);

byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int N;

// Useless?
for ( int i=0; i<1024; ++i ) buffer[i]=0;

while ( (N=S.getInputStream().read(buffer)) != -1 )
{
    String str = new String( buffer, 0, N, "UTF-8" ); // <-- HERE!
}
```

When I establish connection with PuTTY, the string `str` is always garbaged for the **first** readout. After that, everything runs correctly.

Here is an example of what the string looks like:

*What I send*: `Première ligne` (with \r\n added when I hit Enter).

*What I receive*: `ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½'ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½PremiÀ¨re ligne`

(*I don't care about the `è` that doesn't convert correctly, it is not the same problem... I guess!*)

Then, for the rest of the data, **it is correct, there is no garbage**.

Is it a header?

What else?

Comment: do not use Putty telnet, use Putty RAW

Comment: @JIV You're right... So could you tell me what this garbage is? Is it a telnet header or something sent by PuTTY only when in telnet mode (or at least not sent when in raw mode)? Could be interesting to know! ;-)

Comment: Your line which you wonder whether it is useless is: by default all elements of a byte array are 0 at init time. The JLS guarantees that.

Comment: Your byte-string conversion could fail if the socket buffer doesn't contain a complete UTF-8 code sequence (eg, the sender wrote data that crossed some internal buffer, and the trailing bytes are waiting to be put on the wire). A better solution is to wrap your stream with an `InputStreamReader` that specifies encoding.

Comment: @kdgregory Seems logical... I'll do it!